# OpenMP get_num_threads for parallel for

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

What's the best way to find the number of threads that will be used for an omp `parallel for`? I want to allocate enough memory for use with all the threads, but can't make use of `omp_get_num_threads` until I'm inside the parallel section. For instance:

```
int thread_count = ?
float *data = (float*)malloc(thread_count * data_count * sizeof(float));

#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(x)
for (x=0; x<N; x++)
{
    int threadid = omp_get_thread_num();
    //... do stuff with data
}

free(data);
```

What's the proper way of doing it so that I can know how many threads will be used and can allocate accordingly? Thanks

Comment: `omp_get_num_threads` should work before the parallel section. What is the exact problem?

Comment: `omp_get_num_threads` only returns the number of threads in the current section. So it would return `1` if used above.

Comment: Sorry, `omp_get_max_threads` is the answer. If you still doubt, then you can create a *null* `omp parallel for` that contains only call of `omp_get_num_threads` to check the number of worker threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a call to `omp_get_max_threads()`.

Comment: I'm working on a dual C/Fortran project and Fortran has a slightly different approach to OpenMP using parallel blocks so that omp_get_num_threads can be used in this context. It'd be good to be able to know exactly how many would be used. But this is probably the best approach.

Comment: Yeah, I might allocate more memory than is needed but it does the trick.